# Toggle Dropdown but not from checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://liveweave.com/Yyss6U

All headers toggle the visibility of the my next element.

However I put a checkbox element inside one of the header tags, and I don't want to toggle the dropdown when I'm adjusting the checkbox.

I tried using the .not event handler and the not css selector.

How can I solve this problem?

```
$("#toolbox header:not(input[type=checkbox])").on('mouseup touchend', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("activedrop").next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: It was to show that it was not working. After I changed `!==` to `===` and did various experiments using `e.target` with `.prop()` none of them seemed to work. Not sure why #RichardTowers's answer works on my fiddle = http://liveweave.com/l1JB0W My guess is because it's declaring whatever element inside of header will change it's property itself and does not designate the original operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just exclude checkboxes:

```
$("#toolbox header").on('mouseup touchend', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).prop('type') !== 'checkbox' )
        $(this).toggleClass("activedrop").next().toggle();
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Bw2h/5/)

Comment: @DavidThomas - It's a valid point, and as I'm not sure that every element does in fact have a type in older browser (they should though), I'll make it more jQuery'ish, so at least it fails silently.

Comment: Not worth a separate answer but you can also check that the click originates from the header itself if that's the desired behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/Au3va/.

Comment: Can someone explain why `e.target = this` works (as in #RichardTowers answer) and why stating the property as shown in #adeneo answer is not working in my fiddle? - http://liveweave.com/l1JB0W

Comment: @mikethedj4 - `e.target == this` compares the target to the bound element, in other words it checks that the clicked element is in fact `header`, the bound element, and not something further down that just bubbles.